expected value of pairs drawn
Let's say we have 10 balls of 5 different colors: 2 red, 2 blue, 2 orange, 2 green and 2 white. We extract 5 balls at random. What is the expected value of pairs that we can get?
The way I approach this is the following: We can get 0, 1 or 2 pairs, so I'm trying to compute the probabilities of getting each times the number of pairs. The denominator for each probability is 10C5.
Now, for extracting exactly 1 pair, I am thinking the nominator should be: 5 * 4 *3 *2 * 2^3, since firstly there are 5 choices for 1st pair, 2C2 ways to extract the pair, and then 4 ways to choose the second color but we can only extract 1 out of the 2 balls available, so 2C1=2. And so on...
Is my reasoning correct or am I overcounting? Thanks for help in advance.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Hint:  For problems like this it it tends to be much better to use Linearity of Expectation.  Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for each of the five colors.  What can you say about $E[X_i]$?

Try to add intermediate questions. As lulu suggests, you can start with 'probability to obtain 2 blue balls, and no other pair'. And then, you have the tools to answer the exercise. One intermediate question may be also : what is the probability that the first 2 balls are same color, and the 3 others are 3 different colors.

To check if you overcount, you can count probability to have 0 pair, then 1 pair, then 2 pairs. If the sum of those 3 results is 1, you are probably right. Else, you are surely wrong.

On the one hand, I agree with Lulu's comment that linearity of expectation is the way to go.  Label the selected balls $~S-1, ~S-2, ~S-3, ~S-4, ~S-5.~$  Given $~a,b \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}, ~$ such that $~a \neq b, ~$ the probability of $~S-a~$ and $~S-b~$ being the same color is $~\dfrac{1}{9}.$
This is because, with $~S-a~$ selected, there are $~9~$ balls remaining, only one of which will match.
Further, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{2} = 10~$ different pairs of $~S-1, ~S-2, ~S-3, ~S-4, ~S-5,~$ that might result in a match.
Therefore, the expectation is $~\dfrac{1}{9} \times 10 = \dfrac{10}{9}.~$
See also Linearity of Expectation,
which includes a proof that the formula applies even when the events are not
independent of each other.
Edit
See also Graham Kemp's comment, following this answer, which provides an (alternate) color-based application of linearity of expectation, for this problem.

However, since your approach contains an analytical mistake, it is worth exploring where you went wrong.
For $~a = \{0,1,2\},~$ if you let $~p(a)~$ denote the probability of $~a~$ pairs, then the expected number of pairs is
$$\sum_{a=0}^2 [ ~a \times p(a) ~].$$
Further, you can express $~p(a)~$ as
$$\frac{N(a)}{D} ~: ~D = \binom{10}{5} = 252.$$
So, the problem reduces to computing $~N(a) ~: ~a \in \{0,1,2\}.$
The first thing to recognize is that in a combinatorics oriented probability problem, when you use an expression like $~\dfrac{N}{D},~$ you must be consistent in the assumptions made when computing $~N~$ and $~D.$
The $~D = \displaystyle \binom{10}{5} = 252~$ computation contains two assumptions:

Balls of the same color are distinguishable:
So, in effect you are labeling the balls
Red-1, Red-2, Blue-1, Blue-2, ..., White-1, White-2.

The order that the balls are selected is irrelevant. 
For example, choosing Red-1 and then Blue-1 is to be regarded as the same as choosing Blue-1 and then Red-1.


With the above assumptions in mind,
$$N(0) = 2^5 = 32. \tag1 $$
That is, in (1) above, you have $~2~$ choices as to which of each color will be selected.
$$N(2) = \binom{5}{2} \times 6 = 60. \tag2 $$
That is, in (2) above, you have $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{2}~$ choices for the two colors that will produce pairs.  Once these pairs are determined, there will then always be $~6~$ other balls to select as the odd man out.
At this point, one way to proceed is to reason that $~N(1)~$ must be
$$N(1) = \binom{10}{5} - N(0) - N(2) = 252 - 32 - 60 = 160.$$
However, alternatively, to compute $~N(1)~$ from scratch, you could reason that

There are $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{1}~$ ways of determining which color will yield a pair.

Then, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{1}~$ ways of determining which color will be the color omitted.

Then, for the $~3~$ remaining colors, there are $~2^3~$ ways of choosing one of the two balls, from each of these $~3~$ colors.


So,
$$N(1) = 5 \times 4 \times 2^3 = 160.$$
Your computation of $~N(1)~$ was wrong, because (apparently) you assumed that the order that the $~3~$ colors were chosen was relevant, which is inconsistent with using $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{5}~$ as the denominator.
So, using your approach, the expectation is computed as
$$\frac{1}{252} \times \left[ ~(0 \times 32) + (1 \times 160) + (2 \times 60) ~\right]$$
$$= \frac{280}{252} = \frac{70}{63} = \frac{10}{9}.$$

There are five colours, with two of each. Let $X_i$ be the indicator that a pair in colour $i$ is selected (equalling $1$ if so, $0$ if not). For each colour, $\mathsf E(X_i)=\left.\tbinom{2}2\tbinom{8}3\middle/\tbinom{10}5\right.=2/9$. By the Linearity of Expectation: $\mathsf E(X) =\sum_{i=1}^5\mathsf E(X_i) = 10/9$

@GrahamKemp Interesting comment; answer edited to refer to your comment.  Is my position based linearity of expectation approach also valid?

Yes, of course.
